# Equality for same value with and without quotes in bash

Tags: json, bash, date, comparison, quoting

I have this code

```sh
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
date_in_config=$(cat config.json  | jq ".date")
echo $date_in_config
echo $today

if [ $date_in_config == $today ];then
  echo "Same date"
else
  echo "different"
fi
```

**config.json**

```json
{
  "date": "2021-03-24",
  "session": "0"
}
```

I am stuck at comparing the dates. The output that I get from the above code is

```
"2021-03-24"
2021-03-24
different
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you have already detected what is wrong: For Bash (and any other programming language I can think of), `"x"` is different from `x`.

- Put the double-quotes in `today`:

  ```
  today=$(date +'"%Y-%m-%d"')
  ```
- **Or** remove the quotes when retrieving the JSON information:

  ```
  date_in_config=$(jq -r ".date" < config.json)
  ```

And remember to quote your variable expansions, as [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) would have told you. Also get rid of the `==` [bashism](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) (optional, for portability).

```
[ "$date_in_config" = "$today" ]
```